# How to check that item in a list or enumerable template is not null in linq

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a method where I have a request and a template list.  How do I remove null items in the list that references to any Template?  See code below.

Since I don't know the type I can't check for a specific parameter unless that parameter has a typeof I can referece.

```
public List<T> ListTest(MyRequest request, IEnumerable<T> mylist)
{
  var stuff = GetStuff(request);
  var noNullList = mylist.AsQueryable().Where(item != null);  // <-- Error
  return noNullList;
}
```

Comment: You should properly return a List<T> instead of an IEnumerable<T>, so that your code compiles :-)

Answer (score 4):

The line with the error should be

```
var noNullList = mylist.AsQueryable().Where(item => item != null).ToList();
```

Also, what is the reason you used `AsQueryable()`?

Since `mylist` implements `IEnumerable` interface you could just say

```
var noNullList = mylist.Where(item => item != null).ToList();
```

Comment: Updated my answer with `.ToList()` as @Jens Kloster spotted.

Answer (score 3):

You were close. You are missing the item in your lambda expression:

```
public List<T> ListTest(MyRequest request, IEnumerable<T> mylist)
{
  var stuff = GetStuff(request);
  var noNullList = mylist.AsQueryable().Where(item => item != null).ToList();  // <-- Error
  return noNullList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need another parameter for `Where` extension method : it takes an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, not just a boolean.

if you don't use `AsQueryable()`, it's a `Func<T, bool>`, but will "look the same".

```
Where(m => m != null)
```